# Positioning grid of images inside div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a square grid of four images and place them just to the right of some header-text, which has been centered.

Now I have created a plnkr which is a very poor attempt at this - please forgive me, but my CSS skills are practically non-existent. The HTML is:

```
<div class="header">Square To My Right Please!

  <span>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
  </span>

</div>
```

This does get the general box-grid of images I am trying to get, but it places them underneath the header text, instead of just to right. I thought when I put the stuff in the  it would be placed inline, and not on a new row?

The css for the header is:

```
.header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

The plnkr is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9UPppkLcJDd9URgOC8JO

Comment: Try to use `display:inline;`

Comment: @user980828 How does that work?

Comment: Like this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wmNUL20z7TyZc7ZnqwHN?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot encapsulate a block level element like `<div>` inside an inline element like `<span>`. It is like you are putting a box inside a liquid, not liquid inside a box. But anyway, give the `span` a `float: right`.

```css
span {float: right;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Square To My Right Please!
  <span>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Or the second one would be `display: inline-block;`:

```css
span {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Square To My Right Please!
  <span>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Or if you want it middle, give `vertical-align: middle`.

```css
span {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Square To My Right Please!
  <span>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: So if I want to avoid writing the div inside the span, what would you recommend doing?

Comment: Use another block level element or better use another `<div>`. As simple as it is. You can have nested `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change your markup structure as well, it is not good practice to write div inside span

```css
.floatL {
  float: left;
}
.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div class="floatL"><span>Square To My Right Please!</span></div>

  <div class="floatL">
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
      <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this http://plnkr.co/edit/wOukuoOFssqrJoX0mxqr?p=preview

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="left">Square To My Right Please!</div>
  <div class="right">
        <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
        <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
        <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
        <span><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.right span img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```